# Express-node server return empty array on GET

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, callback

```
app.get('/:user/:tag', function (req, res) {
 fs.readdir( 'api'+path.sep+req.params.user, function (err, files) {
    var tweets=[];
    for (var i =1, j=files.length ; i <j; i++)
    {
          fs.readFile('api'+path.sep+req.params.user+path.sep+files[i],'utf8', function (err, data)
           {
                data=JSON.parse(data);
                if (data.tag==req.params.tag){tweets.push(data);};         
           });
    };
    res.send(tweets);
 });
});
```

It seems that problem is fs method's callbacks, but I can't solve it for a long time.

Comment: Your readfile function is async. You should probably use a sync version of this function.

Comment: You have a race condition since `fs.readFile` is asynchronous which is causing your `res.send` to be called before any read is done.  This is the same problem with your `for` loop.  You might want to have a look making it all `async` or using the `sync` version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,fs.readFile() is async method so your response with empty tweets.
Try this code

```
        app.get('/:user/:tag', function (req, res) {
         fs.readdir( 'api'+path.sep+req.params.user, function (err, files) {
if(files.length==0){
res.send([]);
}else{
            var tweets=[];
            for (var i =0, j=files.length ; i <j; i++)
            {
                  fs.readFile('api'+path.sep+req.params.user+path.sep+files[i],'utf8', function (err, data)
                   {
                        data=JSON.parse(data);
                        if (data.tag==req.params.tag){tweets.push(data);}; 
                        if(i==j-1){
                            res.send(tweets);
                          }        
                   });
            };
           }
         });
        });
```